# Cross Deploying Java

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, cross-platform, ubuntu-server

I have a java project which consists on 3 classes(Program,Proxy,Events) from which Program has the main function on it.

I have a Properties file in the same level as src folder.

I want to deploy this project so that i can run it in a cronjob on a ubuntu server but i have no idea how to do so.

1- How do i deploy it? i can only see 3 .class in the bin folder, i thought i would get only 1 output file of some sort.

2- Where do i put my settings file when deployed?

Using Eclipse BTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the directory, in a terminal, run `java Program` to run your application. You'll want your settings file in the same directory (depending on how you are loading it in your code, but if you are loading it as a classpath resource, that would be the spot to put it).

Alternatively, if you want to have a single file, in eclipse, you can export your code to a JAR file:

- File > Export > Java > Runnable Jar File
- Pick your project
- Choose a filename for the JAR (usually ending in the .jar extension)
- On the last page of the wizard, choose Program as your main class

To run it, enter `java -jar XYZ.jar` where XYZ.jar is what you named it.

Comment: Thanks, did work, just that when i run the code i get an error that i don't have the driver for mysql, and i did select it on the jar export, it is located on a directory called external